# How do I print only 2 of the specific functions?

Tags: c++

I am trying to display only functions 1 and 3, but I am unable to figure out how to print them out, as it just prints out all of them.

What do I need to add to print specific things out?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Seminar
{
    int time;
public:
    Seminar()        //Function 1
    {
        time = 30;
        cout << "Seminar starts now" << endl;
    }

    void lecture()        //Function 2
    {
        cout << "Lectures in the seminar on" << endl;
    }

    Seminar(int duration)        //Function 3
    {
        time = duration;
        cout << "Seminar starts now" << endl;
    }

    ~Seminar()        //Function 4
    {
        cout << "Thanks" << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    Seminar();
    Seminar(5);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of them are not printed, function 2 is never called.

Running your code gives:

```
Seminar starts now
Thanks
Seminar starts now
Thanks
```

This is expected, as

1. You call funciton 1: The empty constructor (Seminar starts now)
2. This tempoary object is destroyed and function 4: It's destructor runs (Thanks)
3. You call funciton 3: The paramater constructor (Seminar starts now)
4. This tempoary object is also destroyed and function 4: It's destructor runs again (Thanks)

And the field `time` is never read.

Not sure what behaviour you were expecting, but either way read up on [constructors and destructors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) as you seem to be missunderstanding them somewhat.